# How to handle multiple input forms in Vuex 4.x?

Tags: forms, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, dry

I have a Vue component with 5 input elements. As a exercise to learn VueX I wanted to manage the user input in a Vuex store. Let's assume each input represents a line in a poem. My state, mutation and actions look like that

```
state: {
    poem: {
      line1: '',
      line2: '',
      line3: '',
      line4: '',
      line5: '',
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    setPoem(state, line) {
      state.poem = {...state.poem, ...line}
    },
    resetPoem(state) {
      state.poem = {
        line1: '',
        line2: '',
        line3: '',
        line4: '',
        line5: '',
      }
    }
  },
  actions: {
    setPoem({commit}, line) {
      commit('setPoem', line)
    },
    resetPoem({commit}) {
      commit('resetPoem')
    },
  },
```

Looking the documentation I found that I could use v-model as usual but with a two-way computed property: https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#two-way-computed-property

But it seems not very DRY to create a computed property for each input element like to:

```
computed: {
            line1: {
                get() {
                    return this.$store.state.poem.line1;
                },
                set(value) {
                    this.$store.dispatch('setPoem', {line1: value})
                }
            },
            line2: {
                get() {
                    return this.$store.state.poem.line2;
                },
                set(value) {
                    this.$store.dispatch('setPoem', {line2: value})
                }
            },
            line3: {
                get() {
                    return this.$store.state.poem.line3;
                },
                set(value) {
                    this.$store.dispatch('setPoem', {line3: value})
                }
            },
            line4: {
                get() {
                    return this.$store.state.poem.line4;
                },
                set(value) {
                    this.$store.dispatch('setPoem', {line4: value})
                }
            },
            line5: {
                get() {
                    return this.$store.state.poem.line5;
                },
                set(value) {
                    this.$store.dispatch('setPoem', {line5: value})
                }
            }
        },
```

My template looks like this:

```
<form class="form-group" v-on:submit.prevent="addDocument">
            <input v-model="line1" type="text" />
            <p class="error">{{errorMsg1}}</p>
            <input v-model="line2" type="text" />
            <p class="error">{{errorMsg2}}</p>
            <input v-model="line3" type="text" />
            <p class="error">{{errorMsg3}}</p>
            <input v-model="line4" type="text" />
            <p class="error">{{errorMsg4}}</p>
            <input v-model="line5" type="text" />
            <p class="error">{{errorMsg5}}</p>
            <button type="submit">Send Poem</button>
        </form>
```

How can I refactor this? Is there a best practice to manage state of multiple forms?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [vuex-map-fields](https://github.com/maoberlehner/vuex-map-fields)

```
<script>
import { mapFields } from 'vuex-map-fields';

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapFields([
      'poem.line1',
      'poem.line2',
      'poem.line3',
      // ...
    ]),
  },
};


</script>
```

and in your store, you can import the `getField` and `updateField` to fetch and mutate data

```
...
getters: {
  getField,
},
mutations: {
  updateField,
}
```

---